# NodeJS MySQL concat queries with responses from many model queries to one controller call

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm having problems understanding the async methods on nodejs.

I have this fragment of code in my controller:

```
 app.get(basePath, function (req, res, next) {

        model.generateDB(function (modelErr, modelRes) {
            if (modelErr) console.log('Error: ' + modelErr);
            next(res.send(modelRes));
        });

    });
```

this fragment of code for the model:

```
generateDB: function (next) {

        BDManager.query(
            'INSERT INTO tableName' +
            '(field1, field2) VALUES ("a", "b")',
        function (err, res) { 
            next(err, res); 
        });

    }
```

and this fragment of code for the db manager

```
query: function (sql, next) {

    var con = mysql.createConnection(config.MySQL);

    con.query(sql, function (err, res) {
        if (err) next(err, null);
        next(null, res);
    });

    con.end();

}
```

It works fine for me. the question is how may I have multiple queries with they're responses in the model with only one controller call, like the example (that not works):

```
BDManager.query(
    'INSERT INTO tableName' +
    '(field1, field2) VALUES ("a", "b")',
function (err, res) { 
    next(err, res); 
});
BDManager.query(
    'INSERT INTO tableName' +
    '(field1, field2) VALUES ("a", "b")',
function (err, res) { 
    next(err, res); 
});
BDManager.query(
    'INSERT INTO tableName' +
    '(field1, field2) VALUES ("a", "b")',
function (err, res) { 
    next(err, res); 
});
```

the idea could be to get an array of errors and responses, but I don't know how to send it when all queries finish. I tried with the .then, but it seems that doesn't works (The error I get using .then is "can't use then on null").

Another solution could be to concat many queries in one, but I tried with "; " separator and doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is using callbacks (.then is for promises).  You could create a promise wrapper around it that would let you promisify it and then you could await them or use promise.all if you wanted to run them in parallel.

For example:

```js
function promiseQuery(query, params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    BDManager.query(query, params, function (err, res) {  
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(res);
    });
  });
}


let arrayOfResponses = await Promise.all([
  promiseQuery(query1, params1),
  promiseQuery(query2, params2),
  promiseQuery(query3, params3),
]);
```

Just a few things about that - you probably should be inserting values via parameterized inputs. Your SQL library *should* support that

Also an error will throw a rejection on this.  If you want to catch those errors and push them to an array, you could do that as well with a .catch handler.

If you're not using async/await or a version of node that's compatible, you can also do:

```
Promise.all([]).then(arrayOfResponses => {});
```

As well and that will give you the array of the responses for any promises you pass in to promise.all.

There are tons of articles on how to use Promises and how they work but that should get you started.

Comment: so I have mixed the concepts. Thanks you very much this will help me a lot.